# Where do you translate your apps?

Tags: iphone, localization

I want to localise my app and I am searching a translator to trust. I have found very few so far. icanlocalize.com and gemino.de look good but I know too little about them. I am searching for a company that employs native speakers.
Where do you translate your apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [proz.com](http://www.proz.com/) they are the "union" for small to medium interpreters

Answer (score 0):

I use lang-8.com.  It's not specifically for app translation, but they translate just about everything if you give it your best shot.  Alternatively, you can submit a request to your user base for localization.  Give them a file, like an xml or txt file, with a list of all the words/buttons/whatever you want translated.  Ask them to fill out the form and send it back with the title appname_language, or whatever.

Comment: You might check out Drupal's localization module for an example.  Try to build localization into your app?

Answer (score 0):

I heard good things about [tethras](http://www.tethras.com/)

Never used them myself though.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native Norwegian speaker and know that

http://www.icanlocalize.com/my/invite/28262

uses only native speakers, so join us!! I for sure will do my best to do the very best for you.

Best regards,
Elin B

Comment: I have to say I was keen on these guys, but since they don't reply to questions posted on their contact form, it doesn't really bode well for their translation turnaround time. I got to this stackoverflow post while searching for another option. :)

Answer (score -1):

Since the data is Dynamic ,you can't use String file because one can know the localized word for other words.

So ,its better to add one more Field in web service response which is having the localized word according to localization. Just parse it & make the dynamic localized app.

I had done in this way for an Arabic language.It works well. Hope that could solve your problem unto some extent.